# Material-UI slider not exposing name prop to Formik

Tags: reactjs, slider, material-ui, formik

I'm using react,formik and material-ui to build out an application that I'm trying to add a slider to. For some reason, it appears that the `Material-UI` slider component is not exposing the name prop to formik which causes formik to through a warning and not use the value from the slider. The warning says that you've called `handleChange` but not provided id or name

I've created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-slider-demo-oxegn) that shows the issue I'm having. I managed to find 1 issue on GitHub but Material UII closed it saying that they aren't fixing it and that it has to be handled in userland.

I'm wondering if anyone else has come across this and managed a workaround for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. Changed the `onChange` prop from `onChange={handleChange}` to `onChange={(event, value) => setFieldValue('slider', value)}`

Answer (score 0):

As for now, it already provides a `name` attribute.
https://mui.com/material-ui/api/slide/#props